# Azure Functions - timer function

Tags: azure, azure-functions

we use a timer function that is set on a daily basis .
It then runs for a number of days and then suddenly it stops with the following error:

myTimer 2018-06-02T01:10:00.0612362+00:00

_binder

_context    67b7d674-e7fd-42be-8c40-c3104b5b3d6b

_logger

Failure One or more errors occurred. (Worker process with pid 12488 exited with code 1) (Worker process with pid 11896 exited with code 1) (Worker process with pid 12820 exited with code 1)

I
The way we can resolve this issue is to modify the code a little bit even a new line or a simple space charachter helps it then it contiues to run for days again .

Could you help with this please?

Comment: You should also see an error that looks like this: "ReferenceError: n is not defined", in `UpdateCountFunction\index.js:17:21`. Does that look like a possible issue in the code?

Comment: @Lukas Zumr - if you have an update or small repro of the issue, could you post it? Would love to know how you ran into this issue! (I'm from the Azure Functions team - this shouldn't crash your code or should give you a better error).